# how to give equal spacing between cells of uicollectionview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have added the `UICollectionView` in my app. It works fine but the issue is the spring between the cells is too much. I want to give equal spacing between the cells. On the iPad device I want spaces to be more stretched. Please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: The Flow Layout can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Configure layout
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout_D = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout_D setItemSize:CGSizeMake(102, 96)]; //your cell size
        [flowLayout_D setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [self->mycollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout_D];
```

and you have delegate methods to change the spacing:

```
#pragma mark Collection view layout things

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView==myCollectionView) {
    return 2.0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView==myCollectionView) {
        return 2.0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

You can also change the edge insets:

```
// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    if (collectionView==myCollectionView) {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
    }// top, left, bottom, right
    else
        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);

}
```

Comment: i am not able to provide the margin from edges.

Comment: you can use edge insets for margins,though it doesnt show any  margin visually. Contnetn willbe placed after some padding.